# Fast MDX query for one row per-hierarchy on shared dimension

Tags: union, mdx, rows, hierarchy, dimension

Working on a SSAS multidimensional cube that includes a `UserGroups` dimension made up of multiple hierarchies.  Each hierarchy classifies users as belonging to a particular group or not.  Users can belong to more than one group.

Trying to generate a table with one row for each hierarchy in the dimension.  The best approach that I have come up with is the following:

```
WITH

    MEMBER [Measures].[Group Name] AS
        CASE
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group A].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group A"
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group B].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group B"
            -- More user groups...
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group T].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group T"
            ELSE "Error"
        END
SELECT

{[Members].[Group Name], [Measures].[User Count], [Measures].[Revenue]} ON 0,

Order(
    UNION(
         [UserGroups].[Group A].&[True] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]},


         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].&[True]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]},

        -- A bunch more blocks so that there is one for each row.

         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].&[True]}
    ),
)
ON 1

FROM [Finances];
```

This succeeds in generating the expected table:

```
                    Group Name  User Count  Revenue
All  All  ... True  Group T     90          1800
...  ...  ... ...   ...         ...         ...
All  True ... All   Group B     20          400
True All  ... All   Group A     10          100
```

However, the query is very slow.  Any given row can be calculated in isolation in about 30 seconds.  When combining rows using the `UNION` statement, each additional row seems to result in an exponential increase in computation time rather than the desired linear increase in computation time.

- Why is this increase in time observed?
- Is there a way to instruct the underlying engine to compute each row in isolation?
- Is there simply a better way to issue this query?

Comment: That is surprising each row is so slow. Is User Count a regular SUM measure? How many rows is the fact tables? If you just did a simple query for User Count by Group A how long does it take to retrieve that one cell? How about Revenue? Any other Calculations in play besides what's in the question?

Comment: Do you have latitude to change the cube? A many-to-many UserGroup dimension makes sense. Let me know if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've already experimented with rearranging the query - if you take UNION(...) out of the SELECT and make it a named SET in a WITH clause does that help?

```
WITH
    SET [RowSet] AS
       UNION(
         [UserGroups].[Group A].&[True] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]},


         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].&[True]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]},

        -- A bunch more blocks so that there is one for each row.

         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].&[True]}
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[Group Name] AS
        CASE
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group A].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group A"
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group B].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group B"
            -- More user groups...
            WHEN [UserGroups].[Group T].CurrentMember.MemberValue <> 'All' THEN "Group T"
            ELSE "Error"
        END
SELECT

  {[Members].[Group Name], [Measures].[User Count], [Measures].[Revenue]} ON 0,

  Order(
    [RowSet],
)
ON 1
FROM [Finances];
```

What is the purpose of the ORDER function? I cannot see what you are ordering by?

Again just a shot in the dark but I think sometimes I've noticed differences in efficiency between using UNION and using the `+` operator - so another option:

```
WITH
    SET [RowSet] AS
       {
         [UserGroups].[Group A].&[True] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]}
       }
      +
       {
         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].&[True]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].[All]}
       }

        -- A bunch more blocks so that there is one for each row.
      +
       {
         [UserGroups].[Group A].[All] *
        {[UserGroups].[Group B].[All]} *
        -- More user groups...
        {[UserGroups].[Group T].&[True]}
       }
    MEMBER [Measures].[Group Name] AS
      ...
      ...
```

Apologies I don't have definites - the above are just options that might get lucky!! Best to discuss in as much detail as you can with Greg as he will be able to give you solid advise on possible amendments to the cube design.